# Latex3 array into a table

Tags: tables, expl3, latex3

Now I want to put the data organized in two array in a table.
The procedure works, but I have to write and call it once for the x values and once for the y values.
Is it possible to have a single NewDocumentCommand which can be used for both?
Thank you very much for any advice.

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs} 
%
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
%
\fparray_new:Nn \g_x {6}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {1}{0.907}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {2}{0.875}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {3}{0.845}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {4}{0.817}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {5}{0.701}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {6}{0.613}
%
\fparray_new:Nn \g_y {6}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {1}{27}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {2}{28}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {3}{29}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {4}{30}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {5}{35}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {6}{40}
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcnumd}{o m}
  {\IfValueTF{#1}
     {\num[round-mode = figures, round-precision = #1, round-integer-to-decimal]{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}}
     {\num{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}}
  }
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcx}{o m}
  {
     \fp_set:Nn \indice {\fparray_item:Nn \g_x {#2}}     
     \calcnumd[#1]{\indice}
  }
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcy}{o m}
  {
     \fp_set:Nn \indice {\fparray_item:Nn \g_y {#2}}     
     \calcnumd[#1]{\indice}
  }
%
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
%
\begin{document}

The experimental data are:

\begin{tabular}{l|llllll}
\toprule
$P/\si{\bar}$ & \calcx[4]{1} & \calcx[4]{2} & \calcx[4]{3} & \calcx[4]{4} & \calcx[4]{5} & \calcx[4]{6} \\
$V/\si{\liter}$ & \calcy{1} & \calcy{2} & \calcy{3} & \calcy{4} & \calcy{5} & \calcy{6} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, ***don't*** use names such as `\g_x` that don't conform to the naming scheme of `expl3`. Also `\indice` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `\calcx` and `\calcy` functions into a single function simply by replacing `\fparray_item:Nn` with `\fparray_item:cn` and having `x` or `y`  as a parameter to the new function:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\calc}{omm}
{
    \fp_set:Nn \g_indice_fp {\fparray_item:cn {g_#2} {#3}}
    \calcnumd[#1]{\g_indice_fp}
}
```

Notice that I have also replaced the `\indice` in the OP with an expl3 fp variable `\g_indice_fp`. This is called as `\calc[4]{x}{4}` or `\calc{y}{5}`.

Having done this it is natural to go a step further and replace the multiple calls `\calcy{1}`, ..., `\calcy{6}` with a single function `\Calc{y}{1}{6}`. To do this we just need to add `\int_step_inline:nnn` and an ampersand to the previous definition:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Calc}{ommm}
{
   \int_step_inline:nnn {#3} {#4}
   {
     \fp_gset:Nn \g_indice_fp {\fparray_item:cn {g_#2} {##1}}
     & \calcnumd[#1]{\g_indice_fp}
   }
}
```

Here is the output where the first table uses `\calc` and the second uses `\Calc`:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
%
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
%
\fparray_new:Nn \g_x {6}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {1}{0.907}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {2}{0.875}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {3}{0.845}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {4}{0.817}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {5}{0.701}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_x {6}{0.613}
%
\fparray_new:Nn \g_y {6}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {1}{27}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {2}{28}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {3}{29}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {4}{30}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {5}{35}
\fparray_gset:Nnn \g_y {6}{40}
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcnumd}{o m}
  {\IfValueTF{#1}
     {\num[round-mode = figures, round-precision = #1, round-integer-to-decimal]{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}}
     {\num{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}}
  }
%
\fp_new:N \g_indice_fp
\NewDocumentCommand{\calc}{omm}
{
    \fp_set:Nn \g_indice_fp {\fparray_item:cn {g_#2} {#3}}
    \calcnumd[#1]{\g_indice_fp}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fparray_item:Nn {cn}
% \Calc[offset]{x/y}{start}{finish}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Calc}{ommm}
{
   \int_step_inline:nnn {#3} {#4}
   {
     \fp_gset:Nn \g_indice_fp {\fparray_item:cn {g_#2} {##1}}
     & \calcnumd[#1]{\g_indice_fp}
   }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set:Nn {Nx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fparray_item:Nn {cn}

\ExplSyntaxOff
%
%
\begin{document}

The experimental data are:

\begin{tabular}{l|llllll}
\toprule
$P/\si{\bar}$ & \calc[4]{x}{1} & \calc[4]{x}{2} & \calc[4]{x}{3} & \calc[4]{x}{4} & \calc[4]{x}{5} & \calc[4]{x}{6} \\
$V/\si{\liter}$ & \calc{y}{1} & \calc{y}{2} & \calc{y}{3} & \calc{y}{4} & \calc{y}{5} & \calc{y}{6} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l|llllll}
\toprule
$P/\si{\bar}$   \Calc[4]{x}{1}{6}\\
$V/\si{\liter}$ \Calc{y}{1}{6} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Finally, here is a third version where I have replaced the array names `\g_x` and `\g_y` with names that follow the standard conventions and defined a new command `\ArraySet` to set these arrays:

```
\ArraySet{x}{0.907, 0.875, 0.845, 0.817, 0.701, 0.613}
\ArraySet{y}{27, 28, 29, 30, 35, 40}
```

The output is the same as before. Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
%
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
%
\fparray_new:Nn \g_stalks_x_fparray {6}
\fparray_new:Nn \g_stalks_y_fparray {6}

\int_new:N \l_array_index_int
\NewDocumentCommand\ArraySet{mm}
{
   \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
   \int_zero:N \l_array_index_int
   \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
   {
        \int_incr:N \l_array_index_int
        \fparray_gset:cVo {g_stalks_#1_fparray} \l_array_index_int {##1}
   }
}
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcnumd}{o m}
  {\IfValueTF{#1}
     {\num[round-mode = figures, round-precision = #1, round-integer-to-decimal]{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}}
     {\num{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}}
  }
%
\fp_new:N \g_indice_fp
\NewDocumentCommand{\calc}{omm}
{
    \fp_set:Nn \g_indice_fp {\fparray_item:cn {g_stalks_#2_fparray} {#3}}
    \calcnumd[#1]{\g_indice_fp}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fparray_item:Nn {cn}
% \Calc[offset]{x/y}{start}{finish}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Calc}{ommm}
{
   \int_step_inline:nnn {#3} {#4}
   {
     \fp_gset:Nn \g_indice_fp {\fparray_item:cn {g_stalks_#2_fparray} {##1}}
     & \calcnumd[#1]{\g_indice_fp}
   }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set:Nn {Nx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fparray_item:Nn {cn}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fparray_gset:Nnn {cVo}

\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\ArraySet{x}{0.907, 0.875, 0.845, 0.817, 0.701, 0.613}
\ArraySet{y}{27, 28, 29, 30, 35, 40}

\begin{document}

The experimental data are:

\begin{tabular}{l|llllll}
\toprule
$P/\si{\bar}$ & \calc[4]{x}{1} & \calc[4]{x}{2} & \calc[4]{x}{3} & \calc[4]{x}{4} & \calc[4]{x}{5} & \calc[4]{x}{6} \\
$V/\si{\liter}$ & \calc{y}{1} & \calc{y}{2} & \calc{y}{3} & \calc{y}{4} & \calc{y}{5} & \calc{y}{6} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l|llllll}
\toprule
$P/\si{\bar}$   \Calc[4]{x}{1}{6}\\
$V/\si{\liter}$ \Calc{y}{1}{6} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The "further" solution with Calc also solves many other problems related to the handling of these arrays.

Comment: @AlbyStalks Glad it's helpful. I have just added an `\ArraySet` command as I setting the arrays manually looks painful to me. Rather than hard coding the length of the array as `6` you could also use the `\ArraySet` command to construct the array, using `\clist_count:N` to get the required length.

Comment: There's a lot of useless material, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Please, do avoid such things as `\g_x`. The name should be something like

```
\g_albystalks_x_fparray
```

One of the problems in the current state of LaTeX is that packages use conflicting names for their internal macros. A uniform naming method can avoid such issues.

Now, let's tackle your problem.

There is no need to use `\indice` (another bad name): `\fp_to_decimal:n` will take care of expanding its argument.

A different approach with *symbolic names* can avoid the issue of `\g_x` and keep input simple.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs} 

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcnumd}{o m}
 {
  \IfValueTF{#1}
   {
    \num
     [
      round-mode = figures,
      round-precision = #1,
      round-integer-to-decimal
     ]
     { \fp_to_decimal:n {#2} }
   }
   { \num{ \fp_to_decimal:n {#2} } }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definearray}{mm}
 {
  \albystalks_array_define:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usearray}{mmm}
 {% #1 = array symbolic name
  % #2 = template
  % #3 = separator
  \albystalks_array_use:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arraycount}{m}
 {
  \albystalks_array_count:n { #1 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arrayitem}{mm}
 {
  \albystalks_array_item:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

%%% variables and scratch functions
\seq_new:N \l__albystalks_array_seq
\cs_new:Nn \__albystalks_array:n {}

%%% internal functions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \albystalks_array_define:nn
 {
  \fparray_new:cn { g_albystalks_#1_fparray } { \clist_count:n { #2 } }
  \int_step_inline:nn { \clist_count:n { #2 } }
   {
    \fparray_gset:cnn { g_albystalks_#1_fparray } { ##1 } { \clist_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn\albystalks_array_use:nnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__albystalks_array_seq
  \cs_gset_protected:Nn \__albystalks_array:n { #2 }
  \int_step_inline:nn { \fparray_count:c { g_albystalks_#1_fparray } }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__albystalks_array_seq
     {
      \__albystalks_array:n
       {
        \fparray_item:cn { g_albystalks_#1_fparray } { ##1 }
       }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__albystalks_array_seq { #3 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \albystalks_array_item:nn
 {
  \fparray_item:cn { g_albystalks_#1_fparray } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \albystalks_array_count:n
 {
  \fparray_count:c { g_albystalks_#1_fparray }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definearray{x}{0.907,0.875,0.845,0.817,0.701,0.613}
\definearray{y}{27,28,29,30,35,40}

\begin{document}

The experimental data are:

\begin{tabular}{
  l % header
  *{\arraycount{x}}{l} % as many cols as the x array
}
\toprule
$P$ (\si{\bar})   & \usearray{x}{\calcnumd[4]{#1}}{&} \\
$V$ (\si{\liter}) & \usearray{y}{\calcnumd{#1}}{&} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

With the `c` argument specifier, TeX is instructed to form a control sequence from the (variable) data in the argument.

Simpler strategies are included for populating an array and extracting items or the number thereof from a defined array.

The seemingly complicated `\usearray` macro has as first argument the symbolic name of a defined array; the second argument is a template where `#1` stands for the current item, because the items will be stored one by one and then delivered; the third argument is the separator between items.

[image]

Another example of usage:

```latex
The third item in the ``x'' array is
\begin{enumerate}
\item \arrayitem{x}{3} (raw)
\item \num{\arrayitem{x}{3}} (with \texttt{\string\num})
\item \calcnumd{\arrayitem{x}{3}}
\item \calcnumd[2]{\arrayitem{x}{3}}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: The names to avoid were used only here for the examples. However I will follow your suggestion for a more uniform naming method. The hints I received will be very useful to prepare a problem where for a series of experimental data (x_i,y_i), the regression line is searched with the method of least squares. Calculations and typesetting using LaTeX/LaTeX3.